# Html bootstrap dropdown is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

This is a demo website for a restaurant.
In the menu i want to add a dropdown but it doesnt work.
Nothing happens either i hover or click on menu.
Here is the code:

```
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toogle="dropdown" role="button" >
            Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Desserts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a></li>
          </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>  
  </nav>
```

and the source code:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

please help me. 
*It shows the caret sign but nothing happens after clicking on it*

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Bootstrap docs, it looks like you need to add an id to the button that activates the dropdown and then add `aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"` to the menu part.

Here's an example from the docs

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah... 
What's the use of aria - expanded and aria - haspopup ??

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in the line with the link:

Not data-toogle="dropdown" but data-toggle="dropdown"

Comment: Yeah thanks... I was confused so much. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in this line

Change:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" **data-toogle**="dropdown" role="button">Menu<span class="caret">
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" **data-toggle**="dropdown" role="button">Menu<span class="caret">
```

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
<div class="btn-group first_button">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">**</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>**</li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>**</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Whether aria - expanded should be true or false?

Comment: If the collapsible element is closed by default, it should have a value of aria-expanded="false". If you’ve set the collapsible element to be open by default using the in class, set aria-expanded="true" on the control instead